# How do i compute the Similarity between logical rules

Tags: machine-learning, similarity

I have a similarity problem here. I want to predict the traffic of a new rule using historical data (The traffic of rules implemented in the past). Traffic here means the number of times a rule matched a Person. Here is an example of a Rule :

```
Person.Age<20 and 
(Person.number_of_children==3 or Person.married==True) and 
Person.Work==student and 
Person.Car.isSportCar==False and 
Person.Car.Color in [blue,pink,red]
```

As you can see, in a rule there are a lot of attributes linked with Boolean expressions. The rule matches a person if he and his car satisfy some criteria. To predict the traffic of a rule I have to find a distance or a similarity metric between my rules but I find it difficult to flatten the rules in a column expression. If I do it I’ll lose information and here is why: 
An example of column presentation of my rule :

```
Person.Age : 20
Person.number_of_children:3
Person.married:True
Person.work:student
Person.Car.isSportCar:False
Person.Car.Color:[blue,pink,red]
```

With this I lose the ‘OR’ and ‘<’ and ‘in’

Is flattening my rules expression a good idea or is there another one? Should I convert my rules to another data structure (A tree data structure for example) to better catch the similarity value between them? Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: As your issue is about theory, you should post it on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because higher-level statistics questions belong on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't know there was another platform on stack where i can post stats questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd do in a case like this would be to try to convert the specifications of the rules to sets so flattening them makes sense and then compute a Jaccard distance. Jaccard distance is defined by intersection over union of the sets. Finally, weight the different attributes (or not and use a single set for everything).

For example, given:

> Person.Age<20 and  (Person.number_of_children==3 or
>   Person.married==True) and  Person.Work==student and 
>   Person.Car.isSportCar==False and  Person.Car.Color in [blue,pink,red]

and:

> Person.Age<15 and  (Person.number_of_children==2 or
>   Person.married==False) and  Person.Work==student and 
>   Person.Car.isSportCar==False and  Person.Car.Color in [pink,red,white]

Convert them to something like this:

```
Person.Age (5,5,5,5)
Person.Relatives (Child,Child,Child,Wife)
Person.CarColor (blue,pink,red)

Person.Age (5,5,5)
Person.Relatives (Child,Child)
Person.CarColor (pink,red,white)
```

And then your Jaccard distance will be something like:

```
Person.Age = 3/4
Person.Relatives = 2/4
Person.CarColor = 2/4
```

And aggregate them (weighted if necessary).

Comment: It's indeed an interesting approach but i will have the same problem : I'll lose the information about the logical expressions like 'AND', 'OR'. it's like converting every  logical expression to AND

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest another approach:

Base the similarity score on the percentage of people for whom the two rules give the same result. Of course you'll need a large and heterogeneous population.

If both rules have a similar result for most of the population (e.g. "false") - you may base the score only on test cases where at least one of the rules' result is "true".

Comment: This approach is interesting! I thought about it before but i run onto some complications and i gave up on it. I'll give it another try